# User configuration for TeamCity and Plastic SCM

Tags: teamcity, plasticscm

I'm currently 'playing' with [Plastic](http://www.plasticscm.com) and their (brand new) TeamCity integration plugin.

The plugin blurb says *"When installing Team City on Windows systems, it normally uses the SYSTEM user account. We recommend changing the user that executes the Team City application."*

The thing is, I can't work out what kind of user I should substitute: I would like to be able to access Plastic (on the server) using AD, but wouldn't that mean that TeamCity would also have to run with a network user in order to be able to access Plastic?

An alternative (for me accessing Plastic) would be user/password - but I can't make the TeamCity service run with user/password.

Am I missing something obvious, or is the paint just too wet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm also using PlasticSCM and the Team city plugin, this is my configuration:

For the server: configure your PlasticSCM server with LDAP authentification and select "Active Directory" as the server type.

For the client: configure your PlasticSCM client with LDAP authentification, use your credentials and try the "Test connection" button.

The client setup will generate a "client.conf" file at "C:\Users\your_user\AppData\Local\plastic". This file is used by PlasticSCM client to authenticate with the PlasticSCM server.

So, if your TeamCity service is running with the administrator account you have to place this file in your Administrator "...\AppData\Local\plastic" directory. If you change your TeamCity service to be run with your system account you don't need to do anything, the file is in the right place.

You have another option (if you are still running the TeamCity plugin as Admin), place the "client.conf" file where your "cm.exe" file is. Because the "cm.exe" is going to try to find this file first on its own location and then in the current user "AppData\Local\plastic" directory. This option is only valid if you are the only user working with PlasticSCM in the machine.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Now I'm hitting [this](http://www.plasticscm.net/index.php?/topic/682-problems-with-teamcity-plugin/) though :(